# Input a sentence into C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, input, char

How can I get user input including spaces.

I tried doing this:

```
printf("Enter a sentance: ");
scanf("%s", st);
    getchar();
printf("%s", st);
```

But when I enter 
Hello World
it only returns 
Hello

Comment: Depends how you define "sentence", but you probably want [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  The code you posted is C code.

Answer (score 5):

`scanf` only reads up until the first space, as does `cin >> someString`. What you want, assuming you can use `<iostream>` and `<string>`, is

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
```

This will get all input up until the user hits enter (\n).

Comment: I get this error: "no matching function for call to getline"

Comment: Ah I made a mistake in formatting. It should read "assuming you can use iostream and string". The getline function is defined in the string library.

Comment: "*`scanf` only reads up until the first space*" - actually, `scanf()` itself can read more than 1 word at a time. It is `%s` specifically that stops reading when it encounters whitespace, but you can use something more like `%[^\n]\n` or `%[^.].` instead to read a whole sentence. Just be sure to specify a width to avoid a buffer overflow.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I figured that was outside of the scope of this question, just wanted to keep things simple.

Answer (score 5):

Use fgets() (which has buffer overflow protection) to get your input into a string.

```
printf("Enter a sentance: ");
fgets(st, 256, stdin);
printf("%s", st);
```

Comment: this seemed to work better than using getline, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string st;
    std::cout << "Enter a sentence: ";
    getline(std::cin, st);
    std::cout<< st;
}
```